# make network call parallel without interleaving using rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have use case where I have to make N network calls and I want to receive the data in the order I executed them. What is the best way to do it.

I tried using concat operator but it is inefficient as it is sequential and with merge operator the order of result is undefined.

Comment: With Zip you can wait for all network calls to finish. Each emission could be an ordered ArrayList. Or you can Merge and then Collect all the emissions into an ordered ArrayList again. Afterwards flatMapIterable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload of concat [concatMapEager()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMapEager(rx.functions.Func1)), this will get you the parallelism like `flatMap` while maintaining the source order of emissions.

Comment: Thanks @yosriz. Exactly what I'm looking for :)